# WPF Binding to change fill color of ellipse

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, ellipse

How do I programmatically change the color of an ellipse that is defined in XAML based on a variable?

Everything I've read on binding is based on collections and lists -can't I set it simply (and literally)  based on the value of a string variable?  string color = "red"   color = "#FF0000"

Answer (score 24):

It's worth pointing out that the converter the other posts reference *already exists*, which is why you can do `<Ellipse Fill="red">` in xaml in the first place.  The converter is `System.Windows.Media.BrushConverter`:

```
        BrushConverter bc = new BrushConverter();
        Brush brush = (Brush) bc.ConvertFrom("Red");
```

The more efficient way is to use the full syntax:

```
myEllipse.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
```

**EDIT** in response to -1 and comments:

The code above works perfectly fine *in code*, which is what the original question was asking about.  You also *don't* want an `IValueConverter` - these are typically used for *binding* scenarios.  A `TypeConverter` is the right solution here (because you're one-way converting a string to a brush).  See [this article](http://bryantlikes.com/SilverlightIValueConverterVsTypeConverter.aspx) for details.

**Further edit** (having reread Aviad's comment): you don't need to explicitly use the `TypeConverter` in Xaml - it's used for you.  If I write this in Xaml:

```
<Ellipse Fill="red">
```

... then the runtime automagically uses a `BrushConverter` to turn the string literal into a brush.  That Xaml is essentially converted into the equivalent longhand:

```
<Ellipse>
  <Ellipse.Fill>
     <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFFF0000" />
  </Ellipse.Fill>             
</Ellipse>
```

So you're right - you can't use it in Xaml - but you don't need to.

Even if you had a string value that you wanted to *bind* in as the fill, you don't need to specify the converter manually.  This test from Kaxaml:

```
<Page
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
  <Page.Resources>
    <s:String x:Key="col">Red</s:String>
  </Page.Resources>

  <StackPanel>  
    <Ellipse Width="20" Height="20" Fill="{Binding Source={StaticResource col}}" />
  </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

Strangely, you can't just use the `StaticResource col` and still have this work - but with the binding it  and automatically uses the `ValueConverter` to turn the string into a brush.

Comment: This does not answer the question, the `BrushConverter` does not implement `IValueConverter` so you cannot use it in XAML.

Comment: Edited my answer rather than replying here because I think it's worth pointing out why I'm right in detail...

Answer (score 7):

what you will need to do is implement a custom converter to convert the colour to the brush object. Something like this...

```
public class ColorToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        System.Drawing.Color col = (System.Drawing.Color)value;
        Color c = Color.FromArgb(col.A, col.R, col.G, col.B);
        return new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(c);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        SolidColorBrush c = (SolidColorBrush)value;
        System.Drawing.Color col = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(c.Color.A, c.Color.R, c.Color.G, c.Color.B);
        return col;
    }
}
```

And then specify that converter in your binding

```
Fill="{Binding Colors.Red, Converter={StaticResource ColorToBrushConverter }"
```

Comment: This would be correct if you'd convert to a `Brush` object instead of a `Color` object. Simply using a `BrushConverter` instead of a `ColorConverter` should do the trick. Although I think you need an instance of that converter, the `ConvertFromString` method is not static, is it?

Comment: If you bind using a color then you are free to use the Colors class which has intellisense on the color names as well.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
System.Windows.Media
```

If the name of your ellipse in your XAML is `my_ellipse`,
write something like this:

```
my_ellipse.Fill = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red;
```

or this:

```
my_ellipse.Fill = (SolidColorBrush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFromString("#F4F4F5")
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick work around for this (Although its not binding, and less efficient) is to check the status of an object/element and update the new/other object(s) based on the status, I'll provide a Basic Example Below.

You can do this in MVVM by getting the status of MainWindow Objects from a User Control and changing whatever you want from the MainWindow object status.

Note: this will not work for 2 themed applications and other scenarios where more than basic use case is needed. (Example: Dark Mode, Etc)

In my example, I am using  data to draw a "text" on screen (FrontFog_Text, Which is why the text is using the .Fill Property in my case).

I am not using this in my application but came across this when testing a few things so I thought I would share in this thread while I search for my answer!

```
 private void FrontFog_ToggleButton_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (((MainWindow)App.Current.MainWindow).Theme_Control.IsChecked == true)
        {
            FrontFog_Text.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.White);
        }
        else if (((MainWindow)App.Current.MainWindow).Theme_Control.IsChecked == false)
        {
            FrontFog_Text.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Black);
        }
    }
```